# java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed when downloading image file in android java

Tags: java, android, inputstream, httpconnection

I got hte following error

```
05-10 11:14:47.925: W/System.err(9681): java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
05-10 11:14:47.925: W/System.err(9681):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:118)
05-10 11:14:47.925: W/System.err(9681):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:112)
05-10 11:14:47.925: W/System.err(9681):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
05-10 11:14:47.925: W/System.err(9681):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:529)
05-10 11:14:47.925: W/System.err(9681):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:601)
05-10 11:14:47.925: W/System.err(9681):     at com.laroche.NewsMedia.getImageBitmap(NewsMedia.java:132)
05-10 11:14:47.932: W/System.err(9681):     at com.laroche.News.getNewsListByCategoryId(News.java:113)
05-10 11:14:47.932: W/System.err(9681):     at com.laroche.MainActivity$GetDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:112)
05-10 11:14:47.932: W/System.err(9681):     at com.laroche.MainActivity$GetDataTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-10 11:14:47.932: W/System.err(9681):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-10 11:14:47.932: W/System.err(9681):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-10 11:14:47.932: W/System.err(9681):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-10 11:14:47.932: W/System.err(9681):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-10 11:14:47.932: W/System.err(9681):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-10 11:14:47.932: W/System.err(9681):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

in this line of code:

```
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    String urlString = "http://ma2too3a.com:8084/NewsImages/"+imageName;
    try {
        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(ws.OpenHttpConnection(urlString));
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

        saveImage(bmp,imageName,c);
        bufferedInputStream.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where the `OpenHttpConnection()` function is :

```
public InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException{
    InputStream in = null;
    int respobse = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    if(!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("It's not HTTP connection");
    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        respobse = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if(respobse == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            in= httpConn.getInputStream();
            Log.d("HTTP connection","OK");
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("HTTP ERROR",e.toString());
        throw new IOException();
    }
    return in;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ignoring the possible null return from your OpenConnection() method. It would be better to allow that method to just throw its declared exceptions and not catch them internally.